SVG Pan Zoom: On Click Center Group Inside SVG to the Viewport
I am using this SVG Pan Zoom Library: https://github.com/bumbu/svg-pan-zoom
I have prepared a CodePen for you: https://codepen.io/ItsBenedict/pen/vYMbjpK
If you click on a category, the group should be centered to the viewport. The relevant code I am using here is starting at line 36.
var button1 = document.getElementById("cat-1")
button1.addEventListener("click", function() {
    const { left, width, top, height } = button1.getBoundingClientRect();
    customPanBy({x: width/2 - left, y: height/2 - top});
});

At the moment the group is moving to the top left so I guess the calculations are wrong. It looks like I need to use the getSizes from this plugin but I don't know how to use it. Here is another question but I am not really experienced with JavaScript, so I can't get it to work by myself: svg-pan-zoom pan/zoom to any object
If anyone could help me, it would me much appreciated!

I think things got a little confused with the width and height values - this is the repaired JS calculation, using window innerHeight and innerWidth
function customPanBy(amount){ // {x: 1, y: 2}
    var animationTime = 300 // ms
    , animationStepTime = 15 // one frame per 30 ms
    , animationSteps = animationTime / animationStepTime
    , animationStep = 0
    , intervalID = null
    , destX = (window.innerWidth/2) - amount.x
    , destY = (window.innerHeight/2) - amount.y
    , stepX = destX / animationSteps
    , stepY = destY / animationSteps
    

    intervalID = setInterval(function(){
    if (animationStep++ < animationSteps) {
        panZoom.panBy({x: stepX, y: stepY})
    } else {
        // Cancel interval
        clearInterval(intervalID)
    }
    }, animationStepTime)
}

And the update to the button code
var button1 = document.getElementById("cat-1")
button1.addEventListener("click", function() {
    const { left, width, top, height } = button1.getBoundingClientRect();
customPanBy({x: left + width/2, y: top + height/2});
});

And here is the updated codepen: https://codepen.io/lexicalnoscope/pen/NWmoQVM

It looks much better now, thanks a lot! :) However there is still an alignment to the top left of the center of the viewport (center center is desired). I have copied your code into a new CodePen: https://codepen.io/ItsBenedict/pen/QWPYByj I have created a red div showing the middle of the viewport. Do you know why this happens?

Ah ok I see what you were looking to offset initially - the coordinates going in to the function will need to be altered using the width and height of the button as well as that update

I see. Do you know how or is this too complicated? Here is another topic using bbox: https://github.com/bumbu/svg-pan-zoom/issues/381 But I'm failing to implement it by myself.

And here is another solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29607223
However it is using "pan" which has no animation, so it looks like I need to adapt this somehow to "panby". Maybe the links can help if you have time to help me. :)

I've updated the answer with the change to the button calculation as well as an updated codepen - you just have to add width/2 to left instead of the subtraction you had
